# Sequelize ORM, not showing logs for Model.update

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I've set logging: console.log inside options when initializing new instance. So something like:

```
sequelize = new Sequelize(
        config.database,
        config.username,
        config.password,
        { logging: console.log }
    );
```

and with this, I can see logs just fine when I am querying the DB, such as findByPk. I get:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `password`, `role`, `apiKey`, `resetPasswordToken`, `resetPasswordExpires`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`id` = 3;
```

but when I am doing Model.update, DB updates just fine, but logs are not showing. Am I missing something? Is it possible that I need to pass something else or turn some other option to see logs when calling the update query?

Example of update query:

```
const user = await User.update(
            { safeData },
            { where: { id: ctx.state.user.id }, logging: console.log }
        );
```

I tried passing logging here, but tried without it as well, still nothing is showing up.

Comment: Try removing all logging settings and let sequelize handle it. Because it's already default to console.log

Comment: yeah, tried that, but no luck.